# How to customize the standard report template

Tags: document-classes, templates

I am tired of writing company reports using MS Word, so I am looking for a way to define a custom template that follows the company branding. Basically what I would need to define is the following:

- Enforce font-type and font-size
- Custom color for normal text (some sort of blue) and custom color for the section title, sub-title and sub-sub-title (each have different colors)
- Standardized title page with watermark, document title, author and date
- Standardized last page with watermark, and list of office addresses in a tabular way

Could any one help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on which font you need you might want to consider using xelatex and the fontspec package to set the document font.

The textcolor can be set using color/xcolor packages.

Section titles can be customised using titletoc or sectsty or choose a flexible documentclass like memoir that has customisation tools build-in.

For inspiration on how to change the titlepage see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlepages.

Watermarks can be added with package atbegshi http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi.

Comment: The memoir class seems to have it all actually. Great stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

KOMA-Script classes like `scrreprt` provide such features and many more:

- Any font size is supported, even specified in any TeX unit: a class option might be `fontsize=13pt` or even `fontsize=9bp`, even mm or inch is possible.
- Font type, size, shape and color may be specified for the elements, for instance `\setkomafont{section}{\Large\sffamily\bfseries\color{cyan}}` or `\addtokomafont{\pagenumber}{\itshape}`.
- standardized title pages are available, including title, author, date and even subtitle, even extra (inner) titles are supported
- Documents built on scrreprt are highly customizable, it's easier to use class-built-in features than a lot of extra packages.

Instead of `atbegshi` the package `eso-pic` might be used. The current version (2.0b of 2010/06/08) builds on `atbegshi`, not any more on `everyshi`.

The mentioned `memoir` class goes a similar way by integrating features in the class that would be otherwise available by extra packages.