# LaTeX template for a report

Tags: templates, report

I am fairly new to LaTeX. I am writing a report in LaTeX and I would like to know if anybody can give me the right hint. The Report is a mix of text, tables and graphs. It should have also headers and page numbers. At the best I should make the best use of the space (i.e. many information should be packed in few pages). Can anybody suggesting me the right template for the Report I am trying to write? In general, it would be cool if you know a good site where I can download various templates?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Try this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33480/963

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The LaTeX terminology for a "template" is a "document class".  Standard classes include support for tables.  Extra features may be obtained by loading packages.  The standard repository for classes and packages is [CTAN](ctan.org).  The LaTeX catalogue has a useful [list of classes](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html#classes) and will also be able to point you to classes for tables and graphs.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for that. What I still miss is some examples I can reviwe before I decide which one fits my expectations. If you happen to know some report example I would appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of difficult so say. Are you writing this report just for you or would you like to hand it in as a paper for a magazine or a university?

If you just do it on your own, you can do mainly everything you like. Maybe [How to customize the standard report template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/how-to-customize-the-standard-report-template?rq=1) is a first starting point.

If you want to hand your report in, the magazine or university or whatever may have a complete template or style-guide, how the report should look. The best solution then is to ask them about a template or style-guide and start from there.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I actually have almost full freedom about how the report has to looklike. I just have to use the right colors and fonts. An additional requirement is to have optimal use of the space, but otherwise is up to me. It would be great to see some example in order to make the best choice. Do you know any website where I can find examples? I found the following http://www.howtotex.com/category/templates/. However it is not quite what I am looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A while ago I created a template for me and wrote in my blog about it: http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2224

Comment: Hi Uwe, thanks for that. It quite a nice template but before I start to put some work in it I still would like to compare with others. If you happen to know about other exaples I would appreciate. Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for writing a report would be to [use a standard template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses). Alternatively, you could use something more exotic, e.g., http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/erdc or http://www.cs.sandia.gov/SANDreport/. Personally, I would recommend the standard as a default and the alternatives if you want something that is visually more exciting.